# How to get customable image header?

Tags: images, themes, headers

I'm creating new responsive theme.

How do I get customable theme header image with text inside the image? For ie. Site title in the header image. I read about using 
`add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );` but I can't get it to work.

Point would be that my customer got to option for change the company's header image later if needed.

Comment: *I read about using add_theme_support( 'custom-header' ); but I can't get it to work* Where is your code, what exactly is the issue. Please file an [edit] with your code and explain **exactly** what the issue is. Simply stating it is not working is not a valid description of a failure

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in `functions.php` File of your theme. It will tells your theme to support custom headers:

```
$defaults = array(
    'default-image'          => '',
    'width'                  => 0,
    'height'                 => 0,
    'flex-height'            => false,
    'flex-width'             => false,
    'uploads'                => true,
    'random-default'         => false,
    'header-text'            => true,
    'default-text-color'     => '',
    'wp-head-callback'       => '',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => '',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $defaults );
```

Add this in `Header.php` File of your theme:

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" />
```

> **Recommended :**  [Custom Headers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers) .